# Trying to Multiply Several Values from a table

Tags: mysql

I have been spending most of the day reading and trying to figure this out.  I would like to display a list of post_id when length X width X height => 4000

The meta_value in the table is of type LONGTEXT so it has to be CAST prior to doing any multiplication.  I think maybe my SQL order of operations are wrong.  It's been a while since I have done this stuff.

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key
FROM postmeta
WHERE (
        DECLARE @temp_length = (SELECT meta_value
                              FROM postmeta
                             WHERE meta_key = '_length'),
         @temp_width = (SELECT meta_value
                          FROM postmeta
                         WHERE meta_key = '_width'),

         @temp_height = (SELECT meta_value
                          FROM postmeta
                         WHERE meta_key = '_height')
        AND

    (CAST(@temp_length AS UNSIGNED) * CAST(@temp_width AS UNSIGNED) * CAST(@temp_height AS UNSIGNED) > 250))
ORDER BY post_id;
```

I am getting ERROR:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @temp_length = (SELECT meta_value
                                  FRO' at line 4
```

Comment: You can't put `DECLARE` in a query. It's a statement that's only allowed in stored procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a query that gets each value into a separate column. Then use `HAVING` to filter it based on the product.

```
SELECT post_id,
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_length' THEN meta_value END) AS UNSIGNED) AS temp_length,
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_width' THEN meta_value END) AS UNSIGNED) AS temp_width,
    CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_height' THEN meta_value END) AS UNSIGNED) AS temp_height
FROM postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING temp_length * temp_width * temp_height >= 4000
```

Comment: This works great thanks!  When I studied data structures I don't recall learning "HAVING" I will read up on it to follow your logic.